# v2.6 Primitive method Python code to add circle

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to set up a workflow which involves as many reusable parts as possible.

I've written a vecCircle module which places a circle but it's not working because the example code I used is from a 2.5 doc source and there is no equivalent in 2.6.  I'm using 2.74 and it looks like the API is a 2.6 API - I presume that's right.

The example from
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects

Includes the code

```
ob = bpy.context.object
```

which is an error in my pydev instance due to this being ro in this release. Can anyone tell me how the following should be rewritten? I'm not a python noob but blender Python noob.

```
def createMeshFromPrimitive(name, origin):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(
        vertices=4, 
        radius=1, 
        depth=1, 
        cap_end=True, 
        view_align=False, 
        enter_editmode=False, 
        location=origin, 
        rotation=(0, 0, 0))

    ob = bpy.context.object
    ob.name = name
    ob.show_name = True
    me = ob.data
    me.name = name+'Mesh'
    return ob
```

Comment: are you sure you meant 'Circle' and not 'Cone'  ?

Comment: I want to create circles at the moment, but the code snippet I was hoping could be explained from the old API doc creates cones.

Comment: seen as you are using a much newer version of Blender than is referenced in the 2.5 cookbook, you should read the API of the current release (it has a great search feature) . I've shown you where to find the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet you pasted relies on old API calls, and when it is run in a recent version of Blender it will produce the following exception / Error message

```
TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties: : 
keyword "radius" unrecognized
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Bookmark this link [www.blender.org/api/250PythonDoc/](http://www.blender.org/api/250PythonDoc/), it points at the latest docs automatically. You can also use the help menu.

[image]

See the current API page for [bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_0/bpy.ops.mesh.html?highlight=cone#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add), You'll see that now (September 2015) must specify radius1 or radius2, `radius` doesn't exist anymore. And `cap_end` is now `end_fill_type`

```
Parameters:  

  - vertices (int in [3, 10000000], (optional)) – Vertices
  - radius1 (float in [0, inf], (optional)) – Radius 1
  - radius2 (float in [0, inf], (optional)) – Radius 2
  - depth (float in [0, inf], (optional)) – Depth
  - end_fill_type (enum in [‘NOTHING’, ‘NGON’, ‘TRIFAN’], (optional)) –
  - (....)
```

For the circle example you might use something like this.

```
import bpy

def makePrimitiveCircle(objName, v, r, f, loc, rot, layers=[0]):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(
        vertices=v, 
        radius=r, 
        fill_type=f, 
        view_align=False, 
        enter_editmode=False, 
        location=loc, 
        rotation=rot,
        layers=[(i in layers) for i in range(20)])
    ob = bpy.context.active_object
    ob.name = objName
    ob.show_name = True
    me = ob.data
    me.name = objName + 'Mesh'
    return ob

f = makePrimitiveCircle('pizza', 20, 1.2, 'NGON', (1,2,0), (0,0,0))
print(f)  # does return the new object
# <bpy_struct, Object("pizza")>  


# you could use this to specify layers directly..
makePrimitiveCircle('pizza', 20, 1.2, 'NGON', (1,2,0), (0,0,0), layers=[0,3,5])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The following code in my module did the trick.  Although it meant the scene runs with the most recent object selected.

```
## create mesh and object
#
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=v, radius=r, fill_type=f, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(locX, locY, locY), rotation=(rotX, rotY, rotZ), layers=l)
ob = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
ob.name = objName
ob.show_name = True
me = ob.data
me.name = objName+'Mesh'
return ob
```